# NullPointerException when i call a constructor with arguments

Tags: java

firstly, really sorry for my poor english.
i am trying to make a list of movies.
in main class i call the insert() method and in it i make an object of MovieListNode class in order to do what is needed.

```
class main{...
   while( FileParsers.hasNextMovie() ){
        MovieData movie = FileParsers.getNextMovie();
        System.out.println( movie );
        /* fill the movie lists here */
        UnsortedMovieList vag=new UnsortedMovieList();
        vag.insert(movie);
}
```

the insert method of unsortedmovielist:

```
class UnsortedMovieList{...
 public void insert(MovieData data){

    MovieListNode node=new MovieListNode(data.getId(),data.getTitle(),data.getYear(),data.getRating(),data.getVotes(),data.getDuration(),data.getGenres());

    if(isEmpty()){
            tail=node;
    }else{
        head.setPrevious(node);
    }
    node.setNext(head);
    head=node;
    size++;

}
```

and the MovieListNode class(sorry for the size):

```
public class MovieListNode {

private int id;
private String title;
private int year;
private double rating;
private int votes;
private int duration;
private ArrayList<genre_t> genres;
private int i=0;

private MovieListNode previous;
private MovieListNode next;

public MovieListNode(){}

public MovieListNode(int id, String title, int year, double rating, int votes, int duration, ArrayList<genre_t> genres) {
    this.id=id;
    this.title=title;
    this.year=year;
    this.rating=rating;
    this.votes=votes;
    this.duration=duration;
    this.genres=genres;
}

public int getId() {return id;}
public String getTitle() {return title;}
public int getYear() {return year;}
public double getRating() {return rating;}
public int getVotes() {return votes;}
public int getDuration() {return duration;}
public ArrayList<genre_t> getGenres() {return genres;}
public MovieListNode getPrevious() {return previous;}
public MovieListNode getNext() {return next;}

public void setNext(MovieListNode next) {this.next=next;}
public void setPrevious(MovieListNode previous) {this.previous=previous;}
```

}

when i do this i get `NullPointerException` in line `MovieListNode node=new MovieListNode(data.getId(),data.getTitle(),data.getYear(),data.getRating(),data.getVotes(),data.getDuration(),data.getGenres())`.instead if i write `'MovielistNode node=new MovielistNode();'` i dont get any errors but it's not what i want.
if anyone could help i would be grateful. thanks. (if u want more information about something in my code please let me know)

Comment: Are you sure `data` is not null?

Comment: Perhaps the parsing is returning you a null MovieData object?

Comment: IMO you should also put `UnsortedMovieList vag=new UnsortedMovieList();` before the while loop.

Comment: What does `System.out.println(movie)` in your `main` output?

Comment: Agreed - The MovieData Object must be null. There should be more checks before you call UnsortedMoveList.  Your kitchen sink MovieListNode call with all the arguments passed as method calls as well is not too smart.

Comment: If any of the ints or doubles in MovieData are boxed types (Integer, Double) and they are null this would throw a NPE on that line as well

Comment: It seems like you've omitted some stuff from the routine in `main`. We need to see the whole thing to determine what the error is.

Comment: Why does a MovieListNode contain all the data for a movie as separate fields, instead of just holding the MovieData object? Why do you create a new UnsortedMovieList every time around your while loop, insert one movie in it, and then let it go out of scope?

Comment: @andersschuller data is not null for sure.

Comment: @Anthony Benavente i dont think this happens because if i change the line i said it works fine.

Comment: @ZouZou by doing that nothing changes. the same NPE again

Comment: @alexmac i dont know an other way to do this ... if u have something on mind say it

Comment: Basic debugging could have solved this problem in a few seconds. I suggest you learn how to use a debugger; your IDE (you are using one, right?) should come with one equipped and google will show you how to use it. Although in this case, adding a few print statements would have probably been enough...

Comment: @vaggi, it is your home work.  you figure it out.  You do not have to do it in one whole line, you can do variable assignments and check they return what they expect.   That is my only hint, you have no checks, no try and catch , etc etc .

Comment: @vaggi I know. But not sure if putting inside the loop is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

One or all of the fields in your `MovieData` object are null. You need to investigate your method:

```
FileParsers.getNextMovie();
```

You use this method to initialize an object of type `MovieData` If this method does not declare and initialize a `MoveData` object with a constructor that initializes all of the data fields, and then return that object, you will get a `NullPointer` when you try to call one of the `getters`

It is probably `genres` since the other fields have default initializations.

**UPDATE:**

In your `Fileparsers` class. I notice the code in the `getNextMovie()` method:

```
if( dataLine==null || genresLine==null ) 
  return null; 
}
```

It may be that your logic to `readLine()` is not being used correctly. So I suspect you may be ending up with null lines and therefore returning a null `MovieData` object. You should check if the next line is null before assigning it.

Comment: thanks a lot for your direct answer. according what you said i have well defined tha MovieData class... if u could please take a look https://www.dropbox.com/s/t953f1yebl41toc/MovieData.java  
so what's the problem ?

Comment: @user3448027 I don't think the problem is there. I think its in your static `FileParsers.getNextMovie()` method

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1v7hu06zj34ith3/FileParsers.java
this is FileParsers class, this was given to us and i dont know how to change something in it, however it seems  ok according what u said.